# Writing uneven dict of dicts into separate csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a question on how properly write each "final" nested dict from dict of dicts into separate csv file.

Since the dict of dicts is uneven and has many "layers" I tried to solve it with recursion or to check if the nx element is list, but succeed not. So any clues are highly appreciated.

This is how basically the structure looks like:

```
json = {
   "General":{
      "Column":{
         0:"ID",
         1:"Name",
         2:"Value"
      },
      "Count":{
         0:25,
         1:25,
         2:9
      }
   },
   "Distr":{
      "Name":{
         "":{
            "Value":{
               "Count":{
                  "ID1":12.4,
                  "ID2":29.6,
                  "ID3":9.1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "Digit":{
      "Value":{
         "Std":{
            "2019-04-18 00:00:00":1.5036268714949788,
            "2019-04-23 00:00:00":0.3634739137697553,
            "2019-04-28 00:00:00":0.13565689828487992,
            "2019-05-03 00:00:00":-0.0518006344708256
         },
         "Mean":{
            "2019-04-18 00:00:00":8.7,
            "2019-04-23 00:00:00":1.1,
            "2019-04-28 00:00:00":22.1,
            "2019-05-03 00:00:00":98.5
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: so u have no idea how many layers there r? what is the format of the csv u have in mind?

Comment: @sammywemmy yes, that's the problem is - I have no idea how many layers there are and cannot "hardcode" them. Considering the sample and the expected output: "General"  (Column and Count are columns), is the first dataframe to be written to csv, "Count" is another df, "Value" (Std and Mean are column names) is another df. Smth like this

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> test
{'General': {'Column': {0: 'ID', 1: 'Name', 2: 'Value'}, 'Count': {0: 25, 1: 25, 2: 9}}, 'Distr': {'Name': {'': {'Value': {'Count': {'ID1': 12.4, 'ID2': 29.6, 'ID3': 9.1}}}}}, 'Digit': {'Value': {'Std': {'2019-04-18 00:00:00': 1.5036268714949788, '2019-04-23 00:00:00': 0.3634739137697553, '2019-04-28 00:00:00': 0.13565689828487992, '2019-05-03 00:00:00': -0.0518006344708256}, 'Mean': {'2019-04-18 00:00:00': 8.7, '2019-04-23 00:00:00': 1.1, '2019-04-28 00:00:00': 22.1, '2019-05-03 00:00:00': 98.5}}}}
>>> def create_output(element, column_name):
...     if not isinstance(element, dict):
...         print(f"{column_name}: {element}")
...         return
...     for key, value in element.items():
...         create_output(value, f"{column_name}_{key}")
...
>>> create_output(test, "")
_General_Column_0: ID
_General_Column_1: Name
_General_Column_2: Value
_General_Count_0: 25
_General_Count_1: 25
_General_Count_2: 9
_Distr_Name__Value_Count_ID1: 12.4
_Distr_Name__Value_Count_ID2: 29.6
_Distr_Name__Value_Count_ID3: 9.1
_Digit_Value_Std_2019-04-18 00:00:00: 1.5036268714949788
_Digit_Value_Std_2019-04-23 00:00:00: 0.3634739137697553
_Digit_Value_Std_2019-04-28 00:00:00: 0.13565689828487992
_Digit_Value_Std_2019-05-03 00:00:00: -0.0518006344708256
_Digit_Value_Mean_2019-04-18 00:00:00: 8.7
_Digit_Value_Mean_2019-04-23 00:00:00: 1.1
_Digit_Value_Mean_2019-04-28 00:00:00: 22.1
_Digit_Value_Mean_2019-05-03 00:00:00: 98.5
>>>
```

You can flatten your dictionary. The subdictionary information is then in the key. Use that new key as your column names.

Here I am using `_` as the separator.